# How can I import an existing TFVC repository into Azure DevOps project?

Tags: azure, web-deployment, continuous-deployment, tfvc

I would like to deploy my ASP.NET Web App into Azure. I signed up for a free account on Azure and created a new DevOps Project, but when I select the option "bring your own code", I can only chose to get the code from Git repositories.

[image]

Is there an option to import the code from TFVC, or do I have to migrate my repo to Git?

It seems weird that Microsoft did not include their own technologies (TFVC) into the deployment process, or other popular version control tools (SVN, Mercurial...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the initial release of [Azure DevOps Projects](https://azure.microsoft.com/features/devops-projects/) only supports Git repositories.  Although Azure DevOps Projects do support building a CI/CD pipeline into Azure using *existing* projects, this version is *primarily* meant for bootstrapping new projects, and many new projects are started using Git as the version control system.

Supporting other version control types - especially TFVC - is on the backlog for future improvements.

Comment: OK, I guess I'll have to migrate to Git then! The other thing that bothered me was that I tried to import my existing VSTS project (change logs + user stories and tasks etc.)  into Azure but when I create a new DevOps project > ASP.NET > Web App > If I choose Use Existing VSTS, I will have to create a new project... I can't use the existing one (or is that a limitation of the free trial?). This means I'd have to start from scratch...

Comment: There should be no limitations on the free trial.  But I'm also not sure why you need to create a new project.

Comment: Let's say I want to keep my repository as it is (TFVC), would the only option for me be creating a new project in my existing VSTS account (DevOps project > .NET > ASP.NET Core > Web App > Use existing VSTS) and then manually migrate the code from one project to the other?

Comment: That might work; I don't think you would need to migrate any code.  The only code generated is just a dummy hello world project.  I would try pointing the build system at your existing project first.

Comment: If you have a Azure web app already on which you want to configure CI/CD, you can go to Azure web app and select Continuous Delivery (Preview) option. There you have an option to select TFVC as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** If you use YAML files for defining your build process in VSTS, then the repository is implicitly the same as the one in which your YAML file is present.

You can choose from the following repository types:

[image]

For more details, refer "[Build definition source repositories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/repository#tfvc-options)".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, it's not like I can choose a repository type. We are using TFVC (we are using on prem TFS). I wanted to import my TFVC repo (the code, essentially, along with the change log) into Azure. I noticed that Azure only allows to import Git repos, is there a way to change that?